# An Elegant way to change columns type in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which contains columns of different types, such as integer, character, numeric, and factor.

I need to convert the integer columns to numeric for use in the next step of analysis.

**Example**: `test.data` includes 4 columns (though there are thousands in my real data set): `age`, `gender`, `work.years`, and `name`; `age` and `work.years` are integer, `gender` is factor, and `name` is character. What I need to do is change `age` and `work.years` into a numeric type. And I wrote one piece of code to do this.

```
test.data[sapply(test.data, is.integer)] <-lapply(test.data[sapply(test.data, is.integer)], as.numeric)
```

It looks not good enough though it works. So I am wondering if there is some more elegant methods to fulfill this function. Any creative method will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have other types to be converted to respective classes ?  Otherwise, your option looks good enough.  Other way would be `test.data[] <- lapply(test.data, function(x) if(is.integer(x)) as.numeric(x) else x)`

Comment: @akrun  thanks for reply first! no, in the situation, I just need to convert the integer to numeric and keep the other types without change.

Comment: Okay, in that case either your way or the one I showed in the comments would be fine enough

Comment: You have many lines at your disposal - try assigning the integer check first like `sel <- sapply(test.data, is.integer)` and then it's a lot shorter to apply `test.data[sel] <- lapply(test.data[sel], as.numeric)`

Comment: OK, it's still early in the morning here and I certainly need more coffee. But I have difficulties imagining a situation where it would be required to convert a set of data of the class `integer` to the class `numeric`. Can anyone please give me an example where such an explicit "type casting" would be necessary in R?

Comment: @thelatemail thanks! Yes, it 's clean and easy to understand.

Comment: @RHertel, I think that for example `data.table::melt` gives you a warning when melting several columns that are partly `numeric` and partly `integer`. That's one example why I've also done such conversions before

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks. I obviously need to improve my data.table skills. In base R my understanding is that `integer` is a compatible subset of `numeric`.

Comment: @RHertel, they are also compatible in data.table (it won't run into error), but it generates a warning which in many cases is not desirable for (production) code. The warning in such a case is `'measure.vars' [num, int] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'. All measure variables not of type 'double' will be coerced to. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think elegant code is sometimes subjective.  For me, this is elegant but it may be less efficient compared to the OP's code.  However, as the question is about elegant code, this can be used.

```
test.data[] <- lapply(test.data, function(x) if(is.integer(x)) as.numeric(x) else x)
```

Also, another elegant option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
test.data %<>% 
      mutate_each(funs(if(is.integer(.)) as.numeric(.) else .))
```

Answer (score 21):

Now very elegant in `dplyr` (with `magrittr` `%<>%` operator)

```
test.data %<>% mutate_if(is.integer,as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's tasks like this that I think are best accomplished with explicit loops. You don't buy anything here by replacing a straightforward for-loop with the hidden loop of a function like `lapply()`. Example:

```
## generate data
set.seed(1L);
N <- 3L; test.data <- data.frame(age=sample(20:90,N,T),gender=factor(sample(c('M','F'),N,T)),work.years=sample(1:5,N,T),name=sample(letters,N,T),stringsAsFactors=F);
test.data;
##   age gender work.years name
## 1  38      F          5    b
## 2  46      M          4    f
## 3  60      F          4    e
str(test.data);
## 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ age       : int  38 46 60
##  $ gender    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 1
##  $ work.years: int  5 4 4
##  $ name      : chr  "b" "f" "e"
```

---

```
## solution
for (cn in names(test.data)[sapply(test.data,is.integer)])
    test.data[[cn]] <- as.double(test.data[[cn]]);
```

---

```
## result
test.data;
##   age gender work.years name
## 1  38      F          5    b
## 2  46      M          4    f
## 3  60      F          4    e
str(test.data);
## 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ age       : num  38 46 60
##  $ gender    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 1
##  $ work.years: num  5 4 4
##  $ name      : chr  "b" "f" "e"
```

Comment: @bgoldst thanks! it is not very applicable for the a large number of columns. The test.data I showed is merely an example for easy to express the question. I am sorry that I didn't note that clearly.

Comment: @docendodiscimus @ wanglin I had a misunderstanding of the requirement. I thought you wanted to convert a "known" set of columns from integer to double, not necessarily the entire and exclusive set of columns that are integers. I just edited my solution to work on the entire and exclusive set of columns that are integers. I believe that meets your requirement.

Comment: I normally use the built in libraries but I love this "simply" approach using the for. Thanks for this, and for me the most "elegant" solution;)