# change type of columns in python Datatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

Is it possible to change the `stypes.int8` to `stypes.int32` in python [datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it:

Assume you have a DT and a field type is int32

```
DT = dt.Frame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

and we could like to change its type from int32 to int8 as

```
DT['x'] = dt.int8
```

Here is the syntax:

```
DT['column'] = datatype  # (dt.int32 or dt.str32 etc etcc)
```

Comment: And if you want to change ALL int8 columns into int32, then it's `DT[dt.int8] = dt.int32`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Datatable docs`](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable):

> As the name suggests, the package is closely related to R's data.table and attempts to mimic its core algorithms and API.

So, you can follow this [`link`](https://www.statmethods.net/management/typeconversion.html) and [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315085/an-elegant-way-to-change-columns-type-in-dataframe-in-r?rq=1) for Datatype conversions.